# How to select entities until sum reaches to certain values in jpql?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I found one solution for this question in mysql but it doesn't work with jpa.

```sql
select t.* 
from (select t.*, 
    (@sum := @sum + quantity) as cume_stock 
    from exchange_service.order_book t 
    cross join (select @sum := 0) params order by id 
) t 
where cume_stock < 10000 
or (cume_stock >= 100 and cume_stock - quantity < 10000);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use JPQL? Do you actually need to support multiple databases?

Comment: @JensSchauder cause I don't want to write a native query in jpa repository.

Comment: To be honest that is not a convincing reason. JPQL was never intended as a full replacement for SQL and it is way less powerful.

I don't think it is possible to replace this with JPQL.

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot but it seems there is no alternative for this query in jpa.